# Summary calculation for different times

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the following example for which I'd like to calculate totals at each available time:

```
timestamp  device value
2010-12-30 00:00 1 5
2010-12-30 00:05 1 5
2010-12-30 00:05 2 10
2010-12-30 00:13 1 23
2010-12-30 00:16 3 11
2010-12-30 00:30 1 22
2010-12-30 00:40 2 55
2010-12-30 00:40 3 12
2010-12-30 00:45 2 12
2010-12-30 10:00 3 33
```

At the end the result should look like this:

```
timestamp  Total
2010-12-30 00:00 5
2010-12-30 00:05 5
2010-12-30 00:05 15
2010-12-30 00:13 33
2010-12-30 00:16 44
2010-12-30 00:30 43
2010-12-30 00:40 88
2010-12-30 00:40 89
2010-12-30 00:45 46
2010-12-30 10:00 67
```

The idea is that for each timestamp I need to get the last value for each device and then SUM up the values.

For example:

For timestamp `2010-12-30 00:13` I'd need to take the following entries and SUM them:

```
2010-12-30 00:05 2 10
2010-12-30 00:13 1 23
```

The total would then be 26. For timestamp `2010-12-30 10:00` I'd need to take the following lines:

```
2010-12-30 00:30 1 22
2010-12-30 00:45 2 12
2010-12-30 10:00 3 33
```

Which gives 67 as the total.

My idea was to create a query which would select latest values for each device for each timestamp, but I'm stuck already at selecting the latest values for each device for a specific timestamp, so I'd kindly ask for some support.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: That first sum - for timestamp 2010-12-30 00:13 - shouldn't that be 33 ?? You do mean sum up the 10 and 23 as values, right??

Comment: How many rows are there in your database? Is performance an issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do..... why are there **two output lines** with different results for both 00:05 and 00:40 ??

Comment: Sorry marc_s, yes it should be 33. I used only an example. There can be cases where there are the same timestamps for different devices. I used this only as an example. In real table there is a sequence field which is the primary key. I'd like to calculate the SUM of values for all available devices at each timestamp I have in my table.

Comment: Mark Byers, currently I'm dealing with 150000 lines in this table and I need to have a fast query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach.  The query selects all rows from the table, and then uses `outer apply` to sum up the last value per device.  The `not exists` query filters out rows that are not the last row for that device.

```
select  t1.timestamp
,       last_rows_per_device.Total
from    @t t1
outer apply
        (
        select  sum(t2.value) as Total
        from    @t t2
        where   (
                    t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
                    or (t2.timestamp = t1.timestamp and t2.device <= t1.device)
                ) 
                and not exists
                (
                    select  *
                    from    @t t3
                    where   t3.device = t2.device
                            and t2.timestamp < t3.timestamp 
                            and t3.timestamp <= t1.timestamp
                )
        ) last_rows_per_device
order by
        t1.timestamp
,       t1.device
```

The query assumes that `(timestamp, device)` is unique, and it orders rows with the same timestamp by device id, lowest device first.

This matches your example output:

```
timestamp             Total
2010-12-30 00:00      5
2010-12-30 00:05      5
2010-12-30 00:05      15
2010-12-30 00:13      33
2010-12-30 00:16      44
2010-12-30 00:30      43
2010-12-30 00:40      77
2010-12-30 00:40      89
2010-12-30 00:45      46
2010-12-30 10:00      67
```

Source data:

```
declare @t table (timestamp datetime, device int, value int)
insert @t (timestamp, device, value)
          select '2010-12-30 00:00', 1, 5
union all select '2010-12-30 00:05', 1, 5
union all select '2010-12-30 00:05', 2, 10
union all select '2010-12-30 00:13', 1, 23
union all select '2010-12-30 00:16', 3, 11
union all select '2010-12-30 00:30', 1, 22
union all select '2010-12-30 00:40', 2, 55
union all select '2010-12-30 00:40', 3, 12
union all select '2010-12-30 00:45', 2, 12
union all select '2010-12-30 10:00', 3, 33
```